# Some issues encountered when working with Cardano

Tags: wallet, native-assets

1. How can I generate a bech32 address in the following code:

> ```
> const wallet = new AppWallet({
>   networkId: 0,
>   fetcher: blockchainProvider,
>   submitter: blockchainProvider,
>   key: {
>     type: 'root',
>     bech32: '',
>   },
> });
> ```

2. I want to receive free **tokens** on the preprod network of **Cardano**, how can I do that?